# How to disable screen saver in totem when playing movie?

Tags: 11.10, totem

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

There's a option in Totem that says to disable screen saver while playing movie, but it doesn't work.

Is there anything else I can do to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively use **Caffeine**

> Its a status bar application able to temporarily prevent the
>   activation of both the screensaver and the "sleep" powersaving mode

You can get Caffeine here https://launchpad.net/caffeine or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine python-glade2
```